# Too Many Redirect Error with htaccess for site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was running my site on hostgator global fine with this htaccess. But when I shifted my site to hostgator india server, I started to get TOO MANY REDIRECT error. Can you guys help me to find out what went wrong with this HTACCESS rules ?? I'm still newbie to understand HTACCESS file.

Here are some useful parts of my HTACCESS.

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
#php_flag register_globals on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(,|:|<|>|">|"<|'|http|%|\\\.\.\\|md5|benchmark|union|select|cast|declare|drop|char|exec|meta|script|chmod|chown|wget|cmd|scp|curl|shell_exec|passthru|system|popen|proc_open).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(\=|\@|\[|\]|\^|\`|\{|\}|\~).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*(\'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(<|>|'|CO518|pRiNcE|mowser|vipguyz|itskool|RWAP.IN|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*                            [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(HTTrack|clshttp|archiver|loader|email|nikto|miner|python).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(winhttp|libwww\-perl|curl|wget|harvest|scan|grab|extract).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).*                                [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(,|<|>|"|%0A|%0D|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*                 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(md5|benchmark|union|select|cast|declare|drop|exec|meta|script|chmod|chown|wget|cmd|scp|curl).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}    ^(.*)(<|>|'|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}     ^.*(<|>|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
    # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
    # workaround to get the desired effect:
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_php4.c> 
    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on 
    #php_value zlib.output_compression_level 9 
  </IfModule>
  <Limit GET POST>
  #The next line modified by DenyIP
  order allow,deny
  #The next line modified by DenyIP
  #deny from all
  allow from all
  </Limit>
  <Limit PUT DELETE>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
  </Limit>
  <Files ~ "^\.ht">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
  </Files>
  # Set the default handler.
  DirectoryIndex /web/index.php
  # Protect files from prying eyes.
  <FilesMatch "(\.inc|\.sh|.*sql)$">
  Order allow,deny
  </FilesMatch>
  # disable directory browsing
  Options All -Indexes
  # secure htaccess file
  <Files .htaccess>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  </Files>
```

**Please excuse me if I have asked my question in bad manner. I'm new to all these things.**

Comment: Possibly a subtle syntax issue?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to check your sytnax and split rules then try to find problem causing expression first.

Additionally in my opinion referrer phase might be cause problem. Because every redirection have old one reference.